# 'express' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, express-generator

I am trying to start an express-generator app but I am getting "express is not recognized an internal or external command. I tried all the below
**in windows CMD as administrator**:

```
$ npm install express -g
$ npm install express-generator -g
$ mkdir myApp
$ cd myApp
$ express helloApp
```

the latest command was supposed to create all the express-generator related files (i.e. routes, models, views, etc.). But I am still getting the same error again and again. Any solutions would be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of npm and node are you using?

Comment: node v10.16.3                npm v6.9.0

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using npm < v8.2.0 you need to install it globally (v8.2.0 allows you to use npx). From their documentation:

```
$ npm install -g express-generator
$ express --view=pug myApp
```

You can change the view parameter or even exclude it. This is how I always do it and I just tested it to confirm it works for me although I am using a different version of npm and node than you are.

Comment: hi...did exactly what is above....still same error...can i install a later version of npm?coz you mentioned 8.2.0 and i currently have 6.9.0

Comment: You could update npm/node if that is an option. I also noticed you tried to install express. There may be a chance that you're node_modules isn't in a good state. Are you seeing any errors when you run the first command? Because if the first command executes then the second one should work so I have a feeling you might be getting a permissions issue and possibly have to run the `npm install -g` command with sudo (or the windows equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

try this.

`npm cache clear --force`

```
$ npm install -g express-generator 
$ mkdir myApp
$ cd myApp
$ express helloApp `
```

remember if you are installing globally you need to use `sudo` for `linux` and `mac`, and `powershell` or `admin cmd` to run the code. eg

```
$ sudo npm install -g express-generator
```

Comment: hi Ani...
followed your instructions exactly...launched power shell with admin privileges...executed each and every line above literally...still getting this error....

The term 'express' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. 

do i need to add any environment variables to my system?

Answer (score 0):

i solved the above error by uninstalling node js(v10.16.3) and reinstalling the current version (v12.12.0) ....followed by the known commands:
npm install express -g
npm install express-generator -g 
express project_folder_name
honestly till now i couldn't find any reason for what caused this...but i suppose it was something related to my node_modules directory....
thanks Dillan and Ani for your kind help...your suggestions helped a lot....thanks :)

Comment: You don't need to install express. http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Answer (score 0):

One other possibility - I was unable to use express-generator in vscode. I tried to use it separately in both cmd and powershell. It worked using cmd, but not powershell. Modify vscode to make cmd the default terminal and you're good!

Answer (score 0):

Use npm to install the Express.js package globally on your system. Open the PowerShell terminal and run the following command:

```
npm install -g express
```